# How could I encrypt a file_path with ruby-gpgme?

Tags: ruby, encryption, gnupg, gpgme

I used the following module

https://github.com/ueno/ruby-gpgme

and my encryption code base is something like this:

```
  def encrypt_sign(
    plaintext,
    recipient_pubkey,
    sender_privkey,
    binary: nil,
    password: nil
  )
    in_a_directory(binary) do
      options = pinentry_mode(password)

      GPGME::Ctx.new(options) do |ctx|
        import(sender_privkey)  
        import(recipient_pubkey)

        ctx.add_signer(*(find(sender_privkey, :secret)))
        ctx.encrypt_sign(
          find(recipient_pubkey, :public),
          data(plaintext),
          data,
          GPGME::ENCRYPT_ALWAYS_TRUST
        ).to_s
      end
    end
  end
```

I have no idea how to input file path instead of plaintext file.

any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"Plaintext" in the context of cryptography doesn't refer to actual text but rather to the regular data you want encrypted. So all it should take is passing the file contents as `plaintext`

```
encrypt_sign(File.read(file_path), recipient_pubkey, ...)
```